# SQL function to calculate date format using CASE statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, case

I'm trying to create a function that will return the correct date format depending on what parameter value is entered, but I'm having no luck with the syntax. Can anyone get it to work or have a more efficient/better way to go about doing this?

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_DateFormat
(
    @DateFormat nvarchar(MAX)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(30)
AS
BEGIN
    SET CASE
           WHEN @DateFormat = 'YYYYMMDD' 
             THEN RETURN CONVERT(nvarchar(30), GETDATE(), 112)
           WHEN @DateFormat = 'DD MMM YYYY' 
             THEN RETURN CONVERT(nvarchar(30), GETDATE(), 106)
           ELSE NULL
        END

    RETURN @DateFormat
END;
GO
```

I'm getting the following error messages:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure fn_DateFormat, Line 12
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure fn_DateFormat, Line 14
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHEN'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure fn_DateFormat, Line 15
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure fn_DateFormat, Line 19
>   Incorrect syntax near ';'.

Comment: The parameter is incorrect, use the var. name (i.e. DateFormat).

Comment: Just a guess but I'd expect it to be `SET @VARIABLE = CASE WHEN THEN END`

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is **not** a statement that you can use to control the program flow - it's an **expression** that can only return a value to the caller, e.g. to be stored in a variable

Comment: Reading the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) helps a lot.

Comment: Why are you using a function for this? Is it easier for your users to type `DD MMM YYYY` than to remember `106`? Is it worth the pummeling your performance will take as a result? DRY is a sound principle in a lot of languages, but not in T-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the syntax as a standalone statement:

```
SELECT CASE
        WHEN @DateFormat = 'YYYYMMDD' THEN CONVERT(nvarchar(30), GETDATE(), 112)
        WHEN @DateFormat = 'DD MMM YYYY' THEN CONVERT(nvarchar(30), GETDATE(), 106)
        ELSE @DateFormat
    END
```

And in context as a udf:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_DateFormat
(
    @DateFormat nvarchar(MAX)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(30)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @ret NVARCHAR(30)
    select @ret = 
        CASE
        WHEN @DateFormat = 'YYYYMMDD' THEN CONVERT(nvarchar(30), GETDATE(), 112)
        WHEN @DateFormat = 'DD MMM YYYY' THEN CONVERT(nvarchar(30), GETDATE(), 106)
        ELSE @DateFormat
        end

    return @ret
end
```

Comment: Is there some reason to declare `@DateFormat` as `nvarchar(MAX)` or are you just copying what the OP used?

Comment: Just copying, it's obviously unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You have used `SET` in an incorrect manner.  The correct usage is as given below. Note that `SET` needs to be followed by the variable name that you are trying to set. Also, you should not `RETURN` from inside the `CASE` function. Both these are taken care of in code that I have posted below, which should work without errors.

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_DateFormat
(
    @DateFormat nvarchar(MAX)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(30)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @DateFormat = CASE
           WHEN @DateFormat = 'YYYYMMDD' 
             THEN CONVERT(nvarchar(30), GETDATE(), 112)
           WHEN @DateFormat = 'DD MMM YYYY' 
             THEN CONVERT(nvarchar(30), GETDATE(), 106)
           ELSE NULL
        END

    RETURN @DateFormat
END;
GO
```